# ImageView shows up in unexpected positions in CustomListviews

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview that displays image icon and texts. I'm having a problem with the ViewHolder. I want to simply display the ImageView that animates only in the first position (perhaps the 0's position) , however, the imageView pops up at random positions in custom listview even though the condition is position == 0. 
This happens when I scroll the listview. Whenever I scroll down, more image icon shows up. I am unable to solve this problem for days . I've set up the sample code below .

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customloto7newpack,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // setting up the basic things in here
            holder.left = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.newlotoicons);

            holder.txt_maintext = (TextView) convertView // kumi
                    .findViewById(R.id.loto7newdesu);

            holder.txt_lotodate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.datenew7);
            // You can just add some new stuffs in here
            // new addioitnal
            holder.lotoname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lotoname);
            // holder.txt_mtext = (TextView) convertView
            // .findViewById(R.id.txt_mtext);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (itemkey == 1) {




            holder.lotoname.setText("itemname");
            // setting up the 3 variables in here
            holder.txt_maintext.setText(kai.get(position));
            holder.txt_lotodate.setText("today" + loto_date.get(position));
            if (position == 0) {
                if (newIconParam.get(0).equals("OK")
                        || newIconParam.get(0) == "OK") {

                    dateonly = loto_date.get(0).trim().toString();
                    dateonly2 = dateonly.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\) ?", "");

                    String date3 = dateonly2.trim();// use this to check






                        if (date3.equals(today)) {
                        logicflag = true;
                        holder.left.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blinker);
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.left
                                .getBackground();
                        frameAnimation.start();


                    } else if (!date3
                            .equals(today)) {
                        holder.left.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_icon);

                        // holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                    }
                } else {

                }

            } else {
                holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
```

Actually has more.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stop your animation on other view.
try adding

```
((AnimationDrawable) holder.left).stop();
```

just above

```
holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

in your `else` statement.